Why are the minimums different in R for summary and minimum?
The data set used here is risk (probability) and the probabilities are very small.  When using the summary function in R, the following is obtained
> summary(prob_ann)

##      Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
## 0.000e+00 1.000e-16 1.034e-13 3.959e-12 7.880e-13 8.222e-10

However, a query for the actual minimum yields the correct value:
> min(prob_ann)

## [1] 1.199446e-35

My question is this:  ¿why is summary using scientific notation, but still reporting a TRUE ZERO value instead of the correct value of 1.199e-35?

Update #1
Despite there being more than enough information to "debug" this question (as was demonstrated by the user who actually answered the question), someone "closed" this question because there wasn't enough information to reproduce the problem.  Again, curious that this was the justification when the accepted answer clearly proved them wrong...which raises the question:  ¿why was this question closed?
But, here is the "requested" code:
 set.seed(123)
 prob_ann <- c(1.199446e-35, runif(100, 3.33e-15, 9.99e-10))
 summary(prob_ann)
 min(prob_ann)
 quantile(prob_ann,probs=c(0,1))


Happy to share a miniature data set if that will help.

Pretty sure this relates to floating number precision. If you run all.equal(1.199446e-35, 0) the result is TRUE so for most purposes you could argue that  summary and min return the same value.

From the online doc:  ## S3 method for class data.frame summary(object, maxsum = 7, digits = max(3, getOption("digits")-3), ...).  So try specifying a different value for digits in your call to summary.

As for why it displays differently, summary has its own print method, and it uses the quantile() function to obtain the min and max, not min() and max(), so slightly different code is being executed.

When I set digits=4, it still shows the 0.000e+00.  And when I use the quantile function with probs=c(0,1), it gives correct sci-not with 7 digits.  So...these don't seem to be the issue.

This is a tangent as it doesnt directly answer your question. but you can check your machine precision with .Machine$double.eps ; generally speaking any result that you calculate which is smaller than that shouldnt be considered trustworthy, 'false precision'

You should use ‘summary(log10(prob_ann))’. If you have small probabilities it is always better to work on the log scale.

Even better (more precise) if the probabilities are calculated on the log scale to begin with.

FWIW...(1) I am aware of the machine precision issue; (2) I am working with logs of values when I can (and I can't here); and (3) I'm even using appropriate approximations to work around the machine precision issues like $1-e^{-x}\approx x$.  But I want to know why a function is deciding to report some values accurately with sci-not and not others...and none of these work arounds are helping me address this question.

It's not a TRUE zero value. The reason why the minimum shown by summary differs from the actual minimum is because of the class of the output value.
set.seed(123)
prob_ann <- c(1.199446e-35, runif(100, 0, 8.222e-10))

res <- summary(prob_ann); res
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
0.000e+00 2.003e-10 3.831e-10 4.059e-10 6.203e-10 8.175e-10

min(prob_ann)
[1] 1.199446e-35

class(res)
#[1] "summaryDefault" "table"

The second last line of the summary.default function is:
class(value) <- c("summaryDefault", "table")

the first argument changes the formatting of the output due to the print.summaryDefault function:
function (x, digits = max(3L, getOption("digits") - 3L), ...) 
{
    xx <- x
    if (is.numeric(x) || is.complex(x)) {
        finite <- is.finite(x)
        xx[finite] <- zapsmall(x[finite])
    }
...
    print.table(xx, digits = digits, ...)
    invisible(x)
}

Thus, the output is being rounded (see zapsmall for proof).
?zapsmall


zapsmall determines a digits argument dr for calling round(x, digits =
dr) such that values close to zero (compared with the maximal absolute
value in the vector) are ‘zapped’, i.e., replaced by 0.

If you want to see the unformatted output, then, you can use unclass:
unclass(res)
        Min.      1st Qu.       Median         Mean      3rd Qu.         Max. 
1.199446e-35 2.066278e-10 4.407913e-10 4.176800e-10 6.351261e-10 8.195258e-10

or use print.table instead:
print.table(res)
        Min.      1st Qu.       Median         Mean      3rd Qu.         Max. 
1.199446e-35 2.066278e-10 4.407913e-10 4.176800e-10 6.351261e-10 8.195258e-10


Thanks...my lack of knowledge on the info about the class is what was stumping me.  I will play with this, but I'm guessing if all the probabilities had been < 10^-16, then it would update class automatically to show all #s in proper sci-not.
